# fetching one to many related tables together, pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I have PDO setup and it's working without a problem. I can **add**, **edit**, **del** etc. So the issue is here. There is `one to many` relation in DB and when I fetch the parent table, I want with it come to related child table.

**the DB connection with PDO**.

```
private $server = "localhost";
private $username = "name";
private $password = "password";
private $database = "database_name";

protected function connect(){

    $dns = "mysql:host=" . $this->server . ";dbname=" . $this->database;
    $pdo = new PDO($dns, $this->username, $this->password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $pdo;
}
```

**users class**

```
class Users extends Dbc {

    public function get_users(){

        $sql = "SELECT user.id as u_id, 
        user.user as u_name, 
        schedule.id as s_id, 
        schedule.status as s_status, 
        schedule.content as s_content,
        schedule.return_date as s_date,
        schedule.remarks as s_remarks
        FROM users user
        JOIN schedules schedule ON schedule.user_id = u.id";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $data = [];
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $schedules = [
            'id' => $row['s_id'],
            'status' => $row['s_status'],
            'content' => $row['s_content'],
            'date' => $row['s_date'],
            'remarks' => $row['s_remarks'],
        ];
        if (!isset($data[$row['c_id']])) {
            $row['u_id'] = [
                'id' => $row['u_id'],
                'name' => $row['u_name'],
                'schedules' => [$schedules]
            ];
        } else {
            $row['u_id']['schedules'][] = $schedules;
        }

    echo json_encode($data);


    }   

}
```

this of course returns only `users` table, so what is the right way to fetch users table with child table in it. What do I need to change in PDO...

Comment: By the way, there are two flaws in your code. The loop is essentially useless. $results variable *already* contains the data you need. so you can just `return json_encode($results);` right away. And also, user class should never be extended from a db class, it has many problems. Among other, you are connecting every time a query is executed, which is a BIG no-no!

Comment: a password column has nothing to do with what I said above

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to change in PDO. You just have to change your SQL and the way it is processed. It is explained in my article on [fetching one to many with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/nested_array) but in short, you need to write a query that uses JOIN to fetch records from the child table and then add a condition in the fetching loop to avoid repetitions in the resulting array.

The example is taken from my article as you didn't provide any details about your tables:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id as c_id, c.name as c_name, c.url, 
               p.id as p_id, p.name as p_name, p.price
        FROM category c
        JOIN product p ON p.category_id=c.id
        ORDER BY c.name, p.name
        LIMIT ?,?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$start, $limit]);

$data = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $product = [
        'id' => $row['p_id'],
        'name' => $row['p_name'],
        'price' => $row['price'],
    ];
    if (!isset($data[$row['c_id']])) {
        $row['c_id'] = [
            'name' => $row['c_name'],
            'url' => $row['url'],
            'products' => [$product]
        ];
    } else {
        $row['c_id']['products'][] = $product;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I just tried the sample you provided and something is off I guess, I made mistake at somewhere because error says `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null`. So I updated the question with the new code, and the tables. could you check it out?